# Iterating through JSON using System.Json

Tags: c#, json, .net-4.5

I'm exploring the capabilities of .NET 4.5 `System.Json` library but there isn't much documentation, and it's quite tricky to search for due to the popular JSON.NET library.

I am wondering basically, how I'd loop through some JSON for example:

`{ "People": { "Simon" : { Age: 25 }, "Steve" : { Age: 15 } } }`

I have my JSON in a string, and I want to iterate through and display the ages of everyone.

So first I'd do:

`var jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(myString);`

but then I'm at a loss of what to do next. I'm surprised that the parse method returns a JsonValue not a JsonObject.

What I want to do really is:

```
foreach (var child in jsonObject.Children)
{
  if (child.name == "People")
{
 // another foreach to loop over the people
 // get their name and age, eg. person.Name and person.Children.Age (LINQ this or something)

}

}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the accepted answer does not helped me much because its one of the typcial useles "use this lib its better!" answers i figured that out.

Yes,

```
JsonObject.Parse(myJsonString);
```

Returns a JsonValue object that is the base class of all the Json* classes from System.Json.
When you call JsonObject.Parse(..) then JsonValue.Parse() is really being called because of the inheritance.

to iterate over a JsonObject you can use:

```
var jsonObject = JsonValue.parse(jsonString);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JsonValue> value in jsonObject)
{
    Console.WriteLine("key:" + value.Key);
    Console.WriteLine("value:" + value.Value);
}
```

I dont tried out if this also works if its an JsonArray but maybe if its an JsonArray then you might want to do it with a classic for i:

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonObject.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("value:" + jsonObject[i]);
}
```

If you dont know if its an array or an object than you might check that before

```
if (jsonObject.GetType() == typeof JsonObject){
    //Iterate like an object 
}else if (jsonObject.GetType() == typeof JsonArray){
    //iterate like an array
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) and some Linq

```
string json = @"{ ""People"": { ""Simon"" : { Age: 25 }, ""Steve"" : { Age: 15 } } }";

var people =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json)["People"];

var dict = people.Children()
                 .Cast<JProperty>()
                 .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Value["Age"]);
```

Comment: While I am not the downvoter, I can tell you that the reason you were downvoted is that the original question asked specifically for information pertaining to System.Json, NOT Json.NET. As to why your answer was accepted, even though it wen't directly against the question? Eh.

Answer (score -5):

for that kindly use [json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) library its much better then the system.json itself

```
urclassobj = await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<urclass>(json string)
```

then using foreach with linq on your list of objects

```
 foreach(var details in urclassobj
                        .Select((id) => new { id= id})
                        )
 {
   Console.WriteLine("{0}", details.id);
  }
```

and for object to json its

```
 string json2Send = await JsonConvert.SerializeObjectAsync(urclassobject);
```

Comment: This looks like good info, so I'm not down-voting, but he specifically said that he is trying to learn about how to do things using the `System.Json` library. Given that the question is more about learning than about solving the problem, this doesn't really answer it...